# Unable to view the 3D rendering on the blackberry simulator while using OpenGLES

Tags: blackberry, opengl-es, 3d, blackberry-simulator, opengl-es-2.0

I am right now exploring the openGL ES in the blackberry
I am unable to view the 3D rendering on the simulator(9550) 
but when i upload the cod files on the device it works 
Kindly help.

Could you also suggest any tutorials for blackberry app development using openGLES?

Thank you,
Dheeraj Jami

Comment: When you say "unable to view" does that mean you get a blank canvas?  Are there any exceptions?  Did you check the simulator LGLG log?

Comment: Hi Michael,
yeah i get a blank canvas and nothing else
There are no exceptions and what is LGLG log? 
Where can i find it

Comment: i found the LGLG log and its saying
0:03:09.988: LCD: on
 0:03:10.488: LCD: on
 0:05:31.264: LCD: on
 0:05:31.764: LCD: on
 0:06:27.455: LCD: on
 0:06:27.955: LCD: on
 0:09:50.492: LCD: on
 0:09:51.008: LCD: on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the answer for this problem,
The 3D rendering is not visible because my PC didnt have the updated directx version not installed.